# Why is $ \int_{1}^{9} \frac{dx}{x(\ln(x)^{8/5})}=\infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I get that it’s an improper integral.

Why is the part $\frac {5}{3\ln (t)^{3/5}}$ equal to $+\infty$?

I don’t understand that part.

Comment: Because at lower limit $1$, $\ln (1)=0$ and so does ${\ln (1)}^{\frac 35}$.

Comment: @VikrantDesai Lots of functions do that and don't result in a divergent integral.

Comment: @zhw. I meant after evaluating the integral, when we have $\frac 5{3 {\ln(t)}^{\frac 35}}$ as a term in which we put limits of integral not the integrand.

Comment: Note that $\log(t)=O(t-1)$ as $t\to 1$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $u=\ln x\implies du=\dfrac{dx}{x}$

$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}\displaystyle \int_1^9\dfrac{1}{x(\ln x)^{\frac{8}{5}}}\mathrm{dx}&=\int_0^{\ln 9}\dfrac{1}{u^{\frac{8}{5}}}\mathrm{du}\\&=\dfrac{u^{-\frac{3}{5}}}{-\frac{3}{5}}\bigg|_0^{\ln 9}\\&=-\dfrac{5}{3}u^{-\frac{3}{5}}\bigg|_0^{\ln 9}\\&=-\dfrac{5}{3(\ln 9)^{\frac{3}{5}}}+\lim_\limits{b\to0}\dfrac{5}{3b^{\frac{5}{3}}}\\&=+\infty\end{split}\end{equation}$$